# Shift operators

Tags: java, bit-shift

I  have  this code:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println((-9 >>> 1)); //O/P  2147483643
        System.out.println((-9 >> 1));  //O/P -5
    }
}
```

Correct  me  if  I  am  wrong  in  understanding the following:

The  bit  pattern  for  -9  is

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00001001
```

If shifted to >> right  with  1  position  then

```
1100000 00000000 00000000 00000100
```

This  above  bit  pattern  is  not  equal  to  -5.  How  do these  2  operators  work  on  negative  numbers?  I  do  understand  that  if  they  are  used  on  positive  numbers, then  the  behavior  is  same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit pattern for -9 is not what you think it is.

It's

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111`

Therefore, shifting it by one (not keeping or keeping the sign bit) :

`01111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 // 2147483643`

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 // -5`

Answer (score 2):

Your are having a confusion about how -9 is represented. A simple way is given below,

```
Write the bit pattern for 9
Reverse all the bit
add binary +1 (Binary addition)
```

you will get binary of -9

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001 //9
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110110 //Reverse all the bit
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111 // +1 will give -9
```

I hope that, you might have studied in your childhood days..

Comment: Your  answer  was  very  helpful  too.  Thank  you.  I  was  not  allowed  to  choose  2  answers  as  best  on  this  site.  Thanks  again. @Jaya

Comment: :):) No pblm. Just I have recollected my childhood days :)

Answer (score 1):

The bit pattern for `-9` is not

> ```
> 10000000 00000000 00000000 00001001
> ```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%d = %s%n", -9, Integer.toBinaryString(-9));
    System.out.printf("%d = %s%n", -9 >>> 1,Integer.toBinaryString(-9 >>> 1));
    System.out.printf("%d = %s%n", -9 >> 1, Integer.toBinaryString(-9 >> 1));
}
```

We see the full story is

```
-9 = 11111111111111111111111111110111
2147483643 = 1111111111111111111111111111011
-5 = 11111111111111111111111111111011
```